# How do I prompt a user for confirmation in bash script?

Tags: bash

I want to put a quick "are you sure?" prompt for confirmation at the top of a potentially dangerous bash script, what's the easiest/best way to do this?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231804/in-bash-how-to-add-are-you-sure-y-n-to-any-command-or-alias)

Answer (score 1403, accepted):

```sh
read -p "Are you sure? " -n 1 -r
echo    # (optional) move to a new line
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    # do dangerous stuff
fi
```

I incorporated **levislevis85**'s suggestion (thanks!) and added the `-n` option to `read` to accept one character without the need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can use one or both of these.

Also, the negated form might look like this:

```sh
read -p "Are you sure? " -n 1 -r
echo    # (optional) move to a new line
if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1 # handle exits from shell or function but don't exit interactive shell
fi
```

However, as pointed out by Erich, under some circumstances such as a syntax error caused by the script being run in the wrong shell, the negated form could allow the script to continue to the "dangerous stuff". The failure mode should favor the safest outcome so only the first, non-negated `if` should be used.

### Explanation:

The `read` command outputs the prompt (`-p "prompt"`) then accepts one character (`-n 1`) and accepts backslashes literally (`-r`) (otherwise `read` would see the backslash as an escape and wait for a second character). The default variable for `read` to store the result in is `$REPLY` if you don't supply a name like this: `read -p "my prompt" -n 1 -r my_var`

The `if` statement uses a regular expression to check if the character in `$REPLY` matches (`=~`) an upper or lower case "Y". The regular expression used here says "a string starting (`^`) and consisting solely of one of a list of characters in a bracket expression (`[Yy]`) and ending (`$`)". The anchors (`^` and `$`) prevent matching longer strings. In this case they help reinforce the one-character limit set in the `read` command.

The negated form uses the logical "not" operator (`!`) to match (`=~`) any character that is not "Y" or "y". An alternative way to express this is less readable and doesn't as clearly express the intent in my opinion in this instance. However, this is what it would look like: `if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[^Yy]$ ]]`

Comment: thanks, what do the double square brackets do?

Comment: and can that be negated? i.e. if not match, exit?

Comment: It has more features than `[]` including the regex match operator `=~`. See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: one small issue. If user enters anything that starts with y|Y, it will go through. [[ $a =~ "^[Yy]$" ]]

Comment: after the "read" you should do an "echo" to get the cursor back on the next line. (just a raw "echo" with no params will do the trick)

Comment: The read line should have the variable specified at the end: `read -p "Are you sure? " -n 1 -r REPLY`

Comment: @tuner: `$REPLY` is automatically set if no variable name is supplied.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: with my cygwin-based bash 4.1.10(4) this didn't work somehow.

Comment: @tuner: "didn't work" provides no information. Please describe exactly how it doesn't, because it should in every version of Bash from 3.2 to 4.2 something.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson At first it wouldn't carry out the inner part of the if-clause. Checking again it works. Maybe something with the line endings in the first try. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `-r` option tells `read` not to interpret backslashes as escape characters. I understand it can also be used on the negated form above.

Comment: just a warning on the negated form - if your user runs that in the old Bourne `sh` shell there is a risk that the read and conditional [[ will fail but the script will continue without exiting - perhaps not want you want - the positive version is therefore safer

Comment: @ErichBSchulz: But `sh` doesn't support either `[[` or `=~`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson that's exactly the problem! so if a "bash" script gets run under the old shell (which is possible) the negated form lurches past the test skips the exit... and proceeds straight onto the "dangerous stuff".

Comment: @ErichBSchulz: Odd, I get `[[: not found` for both the negated and non-negated forms when run under `sh`. Which `sh` are you running? Oh, now I see what you mean. You're not talking about the syntax, but the logic. Yes, your point is very much valid!

Comment: What about such a construct: `[[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] || exit -1` How would this be evaluated by an older shell?

Comment: @Scolytus: That will work fine in any shell that supports all the features in use by that statement: double square bracket conditionals, `$REPLY` is the default variable for `read` and regex matching. Taken together, they are supported by Bash >= 3.2, ksh 93 (at least) and zsh (I don't know the version history). The `||` (logical or) construct is supported by most versions of most shells.

Comment: Just to point out - a rookie error in forgetting the hashbang at the top while testing this will throw errors. make sure you add #!/usr/bin/env bash (or similar valid hashbang) to the top of your script

Comment: Can I suggest to insert a `echo ""` just after `fi`? This will send to a new line the cursor, it's just for a better user experience :) Before this, the result output was: `Are you sure? nroot@server:`

Comment: @DJHell: That's a good suggestion. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Can someone breakdown what `=~ ^[Yy]$` is doing/means in the if statement? `if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]`

Comment: @Tony: `=~` is Bash's regex match operator. `^[Yy]$` is a regular expression which means a string which consists only of an upper or lower case y.

Comment: what if I want it to be either y or press enter?

Comment: @PineappleUndertheSea: With Bash 4, you can create a default: `read -p "Are you sure? " -r -i y -e` but the user would need to backspace to be able to change the "y" to an "n", for example. For Bash 3.2 and later, change the pattern in the match in the first example in my answer to `^([Yy]|)$` - this means to match upper or lower case "Y" or nothing (a blank line).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson how would you add coloring for the message ?

Comment: @angry_kiwi: Example: `yellow=$(tput setaf 3); reset=$(tput sgr0); read -p "${yellow}Name: ${reset}"` See `man 5 terminfo` in the Color Handling section for more information. Note that if you use `read -e` for readline support, you should use `\001` and `\002` to wrap the control sequences like this: `yellow=$(tput setaf 3); reset=$(tput sgr0); printf -v prompt "\001${yellow}\002Name: \001${reset}\002"; read -e -p "$prompt"`

Comment: I'm getting 
conditional binary operator expected ,
syntax error near `=~' ,
`if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]'   ..... Oh looks like your example is Bash specific http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206233/what-does-the-operator-do-in-shell-scripts

Comment: @PHPDave: Yes, it's Bash specific. The question is tagged [tag:bash] and "Bash" is in the question title.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou: I added some explanation. Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: In case anyone else has an issue using `read` with a file that has a `/bin/bash` shebang (while using a zsh terminal), this is what worked for me `choice=$(bash -c "read -p 'Are you sure? (y/n) ' -n 1 c; echo \$c")`

Comment: @theOneWhoKnocks: You shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I agree with you, but I had to none the less.

Comment: From where does $REPLY variable come from can someone explain I am new to bash ?

Comment: @SuhailAbdulRehmanChougule: [`$REPLY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-REPLY) is the builtin variable that [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) stores the string it reads in if you don't supply a variable name as an argument. I describe it in my answer in the first paragraph under "Explanation".

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DennisWilliamson but i am getting an usual error "read: illegal option -n"

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DennisWilliamson but i am getting an usual error "read: illegal option -n"  THECODE IN NEXT COMMENT

Comment: ``#!/bin/sh
BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
PROTECTED_BRANCH="master"
MSG="$1"
bug="bug-fix"
if [ "$BRANCH" = "$PROTECTED_BRANCH" ];
then
    echo "inside branch if branch=$BRANCH and protected branch=$PROTECTED_BRANCH"
    if ! grep -qE "bug-fix" "$MSG";
    then
 cat "$MSG"
 echo "Your commit message must contain the word 'bug-fix'"
 exit 1
    else
 exit 0
    fi
else
    read -p "Are you sure you want to commit test (y/n) ?" -n 1 -r
    echo
    if [ "$REPLY" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]
    then
 exit 0
    else
 echo "commit aborted"
 exit 1
    fi
fi``

Comment: @DennisWilliamson the issue got sorted out when instead of #! /bin/sh I used #! /usr/bin/env bash :) Any ways thanks I learned a lot :)

Comment: @SuhailAbdulRehmanChougule: You're welcome. Yes, the shell invoked by `/bin/sh` (Often Dash) usually doesn't support Bash features. In this case, its simpler version of `read` doesn't support the `-n` option which, in Bash, limits the number of characters that `read` accepts.

Comment: `syntax error near unexpected token `fi'`

Comment: To allow a default of `y`, you can make the match group optional with `?`: `if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[yY]?$ ]]`

Comment: Vote down because using unusual `-r` and `-n`'

Comment: I like this better than what I found on the 'duplicate' Q/A

Comment: I think `[[ ${REPLY^} = Y ]]` is slightly easier to understand than a regex. Good answer though.

Comment: Dangerous! If you accidentally hit the Y key twice this will propagate to the next part of the script that requests input, if there is one, which could be quite catastrophic. Probably wise to require the enter key be pressed to end any input.

Comment: One-liner: `read -p "Continue? [Enter] → Yes, [Ctrl]+[C] → No."`.

Comment: `if [[  $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]` is needed to proceed not `if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]`

Comment: Is this standard ? for me the `REPLY`  variable gets the value `e` from the following `echo` then it complains about the unknown `cho` >_>

Comment: @Enissay: You must be entering the commands (or pasting them) at the prompt instead of in a script. The `read` command would execute immediately, waiting for the next input which is the `echo` command. Since the `-n` option is set to accept one character then exit, the "e" goes into the `REPLY` variable and the rest of the line goes to the shell for execution. Since the "e" was read, the rest is "cho ..." which isn't a recognized command. If you want to try this from the command line, enter the `read` command, press a key, then enter the echo command.

Comment: @mikoop: The negated tests proceeds to exiting/returning if something other that Y/y are pressed. If one of those keys is pressed the negated test will fail and execution proceeds past the `if` on to the rest of the script. One of the things this does is prevent one from having to wrap a whole script inside the `if`.

Comment: Suggestion: Show the expected responses and which response is default. `read -p "Are you sure? [y/N] " -n 1 -r` And then, echo a newline unless they hit "Enter". `[[ -z $REPLY ]] || echo`

Answer (score 250):

use case/esac.

```
read -p "Continue (y/n)?" choice
case "$choice" in 
  y|Y ) echo "yes";;
  n|N ) echo "no";;
  * ) echo "invalid";;
esac
```

advantage:

1. neater
2. can use "OR" condition easier
3. can use character range, eg [yY][eE][sS] to accept word "yes", where any of its characters may be in lowercase or in uppercase.

Comment: Good solution. Personally, if the bash script could really be crippling I like to have the person type out 'yes'.

Comment: How can I use this to exit when the input is no (maybe `echo "Quitting script."; exit;;`), but if the input is yes, the script will just continue with whatever comes after `esac`?

Comment: If you do `n|N ) echo "no"; return;;` the script will end there if you say 'n' and continue with the rest otherwise, is that what you mean?

Comment: @SiegeX if it's really, really crippling you could have the user type out "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs" :P

Comment: When the user input is invalid, how to ask the user to input again. And do the 'return;' if got invalid three times.

Answer (score 72):

Try the `read` shell builtin:

```
read -p "Continue (y/n)?" CONT
if [ "$CONT" = "y" ]; then
  echo "yaaa";
else
  echo "booo";
fi
```

Answer (score 59):

This way you get 'y' 'yes' or 'Enter'

```
 read -r -p "Are you sure? [Y/n]" response
 response=${response,,} # tolower
 if [[ $response =~ ^(y| ) ]] || [[ -z $response ]]; then
    your-action-here
 fi
```

If you are using zsh try this:

```
read "response?Are you sure ? [Y/n] "
response=${response:l} #tolower
if [[ $response =~ ^(y| ) ]] || [[ -z $response ]]; then
    your-action-here
fi
```

Comment: Not accepting default Y

Comment: For default Y

if [[ $response =~ ^(yes|y| ) ]] | [ -z $response ]; then

Comment: In the regex, there is no need to match both yes and y, just y beginning is enough. Also, if default needs to be no, then the following would be helpful.

read "response?Are you sure ? [Y/n] " &&  if [[ "$response" =~ ^[Yy] ]]; then echo "Yes, you did it."; else echo "No, narrow escape"; fi

Answer (score 34):

Here's the function I use:

```
function ask_yes_or_no() {
    read -p "$1 ([y]es or [N]o): "
    case $(echo $REPLY | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]') in
        y|yes) echo "yes" ;;
        *)     echo "no" ;;
    esac
}
```

And an example using it:

```
if [[ "no" == $(ask_yes_or_no "Are you sure?") || \
      "no" == $(ask_yes_or_no "Are you *really* sure?") ]]
then
    echo "Skipped."
    exit 0
fi

# Do something really dangerous...
```

- The output is always "yes" or "no"
- It's "no" by default
- Everything except "y" or "yes" returns "no", so it's pretty safe for a dangerous bash script
- And it's case insensitive, "Y", "Yes", or "YES" work as "yes".

Answer (score 26):

This what I found elsewhere, is there a better possible version?

```
read -p "Are you sure you wish to continue?"
if [ "$REPLY" != "yes" ]; then
   exit
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

```
[[ -f ./${sname} ]] && read -p "File exists. Are you sure? " -n 1

[[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] && exit 1
```

used this in a function to look for an existing file and prompt before overwriting.

Answer (score 8):

```
echo are you sure?
read x
if [ "$x" = "yes" ]
then
  # do the dangerous stuff
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Please, enter your name
read NAME
echo "Hi $NAME!"
if [ "x$NAME" = "xyes" ] ; then
 # do something
fi
```

I s a short script to read in bash and echo back results.

Answer (score 3):

qnd: use

```
read VARNAME
echo $VARNAME
```

for a one line response without readline support.  Then test $VARNAME however you want.