# What does the "=~" operator do in shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell

It seems that it is sort of comparison operator, but what exactly it does in e.g. the following code (taken from https://github.com/lvv/git-prompt/blob/master/git-prompt.sh#L154)?

```
    if [[ $LC_CTYPE =~ "UTF" && $TERM != "linux" ]];  then
            elipses_marker="…"
    else
            elipses_marker="..."
    fi
```

I'm currently trying to make `git-prompt` to work under MinGW, and the shell supplied with MinGW doesn't seem to support this operator:

```
conditional binary operator expected
syntax error near `=~'
`        if [[ $LC_CTYPE =~ "UTF" && $TERM != "linux" ]];  then'
```

In this specific case I can just replace the entire block with `elipses_marker="…"` (as I know my terminal supports unicode), but what exactly this `=~` does?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a bash-only addition to the built-in `[[` command, performing regexp matching. Since it doesn't have to be an exact match of the full string, the symbol is waved, to indicate an "inexact" match.

In this case, if `$LC_CTYPE` *CONTAINS* the string "UTF".

More portable version:

```
if test `echo $LC_CTYPE | grep -c UTF` -ne 0 -a "$TERM" != "linux"
then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```

Comment: There is no need to run grep in backticks.  `if echo $LC_TYPE | grep -Fq UTF && test "$TERM" != linux; then`

Comment: Trying to encourage readable code... I find it more intuitive with only one `test` and the backticks surrounding the first "expression", making it look like an expression. (And grep -q would be true on an error as well) :-) But I agree. I have a habit of using `test` too often, but I think it's more readable than `if:ing` a pipe.

Comment: What do you mean by "grep -q would be true on an error as well"?

Comment: Interesting.  For reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html  "If the -q option is specified, the exit status shall be zero if an input line is selected, even if an error was detected. Otherwise, default actions shall be performed."

Comment: It strikes me that grep being successful on an error is actually the desired behavior here, though.

Comment: This is not a bash extension to `[ ]`; it is only found in `[[ ]]`, not bash's implementation of `[ ]`.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "fuzzy" matching. That means something different than "regular expressions".

Answer (score 7):

It's a regular expression matching. I guess your bash version doesn't support that yet.

In this particular case, I'd suggest replacing it with simpler (and faster) pattern matching:

```
[[ $LC_CTYPE == *UTF* && $TERM != "linux" ]]
```

(note that `*` must not be quoted here)

Answer (score 3):

Like Ruby, it matches where the RHS operand is a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

It matches regular expressions

Refer to following example from http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1


if [[ "$input" =~ "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ]]
#                 ^ NOTE: Quoting not necessary, as of version 3.2 of Bash.
# NNN-NN-NNNN (where each N is a digit).
then
  echo "Social Security number."
  # Process SSN.
else
  echo "Not a Social Security number!"
  # Or, ask for corrected input.
fi
```

Comment: If you quote the regex (as of Bash 3.2) it becomes a literal string instead of a regex.