# Best algorithm for fuzzy searching directory names

Tags: algorithm, fuzzy-search

What would be the best/appropriate algorithm for fuzzy search directory names? I would like to implement a bash completion which completes directory/file names using fuzzy search but it seems that the algorithm is dependent on the set of strings to match.

Comment: So what is your set of strings? How many directories do you expect to have to search in? etc., etc. I.e. what do you know about the constraints?

Comment: @IvanVergiliev I want to complete all files in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... this is an interesting proposal.  I would do it something like this:

First, parse the file path to get the text after the last slash

```
IFS='/' read -a filepath <<< '$string'
dirname=${filepath[${#filepath[@] - 1]}
```

Next, use `find` to get all the immediate subdirectories directories in the current path and add them to the bash completion option.  You can use the `=~` operator in place of fuzzy search, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206353/214892)

```
for i in 'find . -type d -maxdepth 1'; do
  if [[ i =~ $dirname ]]; then
    //add to bash completion option, unsure how to do this part
  fi
done
```

However, note that `=~` is a bash-only operator.