# bash, prompt for numerical input

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop, grep

d is an internal server lookup tool I use.

I am looking to allow a user to input any number between 0 (or 1) and 9999 (let's call this userinput) and have it display the result of:

d $userinput (e.g. 1234)

Then manipulate the results of that lookup (below gets rid of everything but the IP address to ping later):

```
 grep -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'`
```

I know I need to use the while true; do read $blah etc etc. I am just not familiar with read enough to format it properly and more importantly:

**get it to prompt for a numerical input between 0-9999**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<--edit-->

if all you want is the mechanic for prompting, try this:

```
echo -n "Enter server number:"
read userinput
```

then run validation checks on the input like this:

```
if [[ $userinput -lt 0 || $userinput -gt 9999 ]]   # checks that the input is within the desired range
 then
  echo "Input outside acceptable range."
else
  # insert your grep and ping stuff here
fi
```

<--end edit-->

on first read, i thought your problem sounded ideal for a wrapper script, so i was going to suggest this:

```
$ cat wrapper.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

userinput=$1

if [[ $# != 1 ]]   # checks that number of inputs is exactly one
 then
  echo "Too many inputs."
  exit 2
elif [[ $userinput -lt 0 || $userinput -gt 9999 ]]   # checks that the input is within the desired range
 then
  echo "Input outside acceptable range."
  exit 3
fi

output=`d "$userinput"`

ping_address=`grep -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' <("$output")`

ping "$ping_address"
```

then call the script with like this:

```
$ wrapper.sh 1243
```

Comment: Perfect edit, thank you so much :) after else I just do d $userinput | grep... and it works a charm.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers have many flaws, because **they check that the user didn't input a number outside of the range they want**. But what if a user enters something that is not a number? their strategy is broken from the start.

Instead it's better to let go only when we're sure that the user entered a number which lies within the wanted range.

```
while :; do
    read -ep 'Enter server number: ' number
    [[ $number =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || continue
    (( ( (number=(10#$number)) <= 9999 ) && number >= 0 )) || continue
    # Here I'm sure that number is a valid number in the range 0..9999
    # So let's break the infinite loop!
    break
done
```

The regex `[[ $number =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]` makes sure that the user only entered digits.

The clumsy `(number=(10#$number))` part is here so that if the user enters a number that starts with a `0`, bash would try to interpret it in radix `8` and we'd get a wrong result (e.g., if the user enters `010`) and even an error in the case when a user enters, e.g., `09` (try it without this guard).

---

If you only want to prompt once and exit when the user inputs invalid terms, you have the logic:

```
read -ep 'Enter server number: ' number
[[ $number =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || exit 1
(( ( (number=(10#$number)) <= 9999 ) && number >= 0 )) || exit 1
# Here I'm sure that number is a valid number in the range 0..9999
```

If you want to explain to the user why the script exited, you can use a die function as:

```
die() {
    (($#)) && printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
    exit 1
}
read -ep 'Enter server number: ' number
[[ $number =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] ||
    die '*** Error: you should have entered a number'
(( ( (number=(10#$number)) <= 9999 ) && number >= 0 )) ||
    die '*** Error, number not in range 0..9999'
# Here I'm sure that number is a valid number in the range 0..9999
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a number between two values, you can test their values:

```
 read x
 while [[ $x -lt 0 || $x -gt 9999 ]]; do
    echo "bad value for x"
    read x
 done
 echo "x=$x"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `read` command doesn't prompt itself. Use a normal `echo` before to actually display a prompt. Use `echo -n` to not add a newline.

Comment: Searching around for "bash prompt for input" just comes back with example of using read like so: read -p "Enter value" variable case "variable" in...how do I prompt via echo or reference read from echo. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885525/how-do-i-prompt-a-user-for-confirmation-in-bash-script

Comment: @Zippyduda The `-p` option is an extension that doesn't exist in the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/read.html).

Comment: Hm, fair enough. Why is it used in that link I posted?

Comment: @Zippyduda Ah, I found it now in the [Bash manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). It's a Bash-specific extension. Have you tried it?