# How can I prompt for yes/no style confirmation in a zsh script?

Tags: bash, scripting, zsh, prompt

Using zsh, I'm trying to put a step in my `~/.zprofile` where I interactively ask a yes/no style question. At first I tried [this bash-style approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885534), but I saw errors of this form:

`read: -p: no coprocess`

(I'm aware that typically the zsh syntax is different from bash's - I tried preceding it with a sh emulation command - `emulate -LR sh` - but it made no difference).

This page implied the syntax might be different, so guided by [this page](http://www.molecularbear.com/blog/?p=442) and the zsh man page, I tried this instead:

`read -q REPLY?"This is the question I want to ask?"`

This instead fails with an error of the form:

`/home/user/.zprofile:5: no matches found: REPLY?"This is the question I want to ask?"`

How can I ask a simple yes/no question with zsh? Ideally the command would just swallow one character, with no need to press Enter/Return, and be 'safe' - i.e. the subsequent test defaults to no/false unless 'Y' or 'y' are entered.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From [zsh - read](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-read)

> If the first argument contains a ‘?’, the remainder of this word is used as a prompt on standard error when the shell is interactive.

You must quote the entire argument

```
read -q "REPLY?This is the question I want to ask?"
```

this will prompt you with `This is the question I want to ask?` and return the character pressed in `REPLY`.

If you don't quote the question mark, `zsh` tries to match the argument as a filename. And if it doesn't find any matching filename, it complains with `no matches found`.

Answer (score 31):

I'm adding this answer because every time you want to ask the user for confirmation, you also want to act on it. here's a function that prompts with `read -q` (thanks, other answers!) and branches on the result to do what you want (in this case, git stuff):

```
git_commit_and_pull() {
    # http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-read
    if read -q "choice?Press Y/y to continue with commit and pull: "; then
        git add . && git commit -m 'haha git goes brrr' && git pull
    else
        echo
        echo "'$choice' not 'Y' or 'y'. Exiting..."
    fi
}
```

Comment: It works!  Thank you! but how does it work?  I don't see a test on choice to tell whether the value actually contains a Y/y.

Comment: @Tongfa It's subtle. the `-q` flag makes `read` return `0` (success) if the input is `Y` or `y`. That return code is tested in the if. See the link in code for the man page

Answer (score 12):

See [ZSH Manual](http://www.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_17.html) for documentation of ZSH's read.  Try:

```
read REPLY\?"This is the question I want to ask?"
```

Comment: Some way to have it working with autocomplete?

Comment: @AdrianLopez Try vared: https://superuser.com/questions/427645/better-way-to-read-a-line-of-user-input-in-zsh-e-g-with-zle

Answer (score 3):

I created two utility scripts for this:

- `read-string.sh` reads a string from input (requires user to press enter)
- `read-char.sh` reads a single char from input (does not require pressing enter)

Both scripts work fine regardless of whether the user is using **bash** or **zsh**.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# read-string.sh
# eg: my_string=$(./read-string.sh); echo "my_string: $my_string"

# bash `read` manual - https://ss64.com/bash/read.html
# 
# read [-ers] [-a aname]  [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars]
#    [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-r] [-s] [-t timeout] [-u fd]
#       [name...]
# 
#  -r        Do not treat a Backslash as an escape character.  The backslash is considered to be part
#            of the line. In particular, a backslash-newline pair can not be used as a line continuation.
#            Without this option, any backslashes in the input will be discarded.
#            You should almost always use the -r option with read.

# zsh `read` manual - http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-read
# 
# read [ -rszpqAclneE ] [ -t [ num ] ] [ -k [ num ] ] [ -d delim ]
#     [ -u n ] [ name[?prompt] ] [ name ... ]
# 
# -r         Raw mode: a ‘\’ at the end of a line does not signify line continuation and backslashes in the line
#            don’t quote the following character and are not removed.

if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
  read -r "answer?"
else
  read -r answer
fi
echo "$answer"
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# eg: my_char=$(read-char.sh); echo "my_char: $my_char"

# bash `read` manual - https://ss64.com/bash/read.html
# 
# read [-ers] [-a aname]  [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars]
#    [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-r] [-s] [-t timeout] [-u fd]
#       [name...]
# 
#  -r        Do not treat a Backslash as an escape character.  The backslash is considered to be part
#            of the line. In particular, a backslash-newline pair can not be used as a line continuation.
#            Without this option, any backslashes in the input will be discarded.
#            You should almost always use the -r option with read.
#  -n nchars read returns after reading nchars characters rather than waiting for a complete line of input.

# zsh `read` manual - http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-read
# 
# read [ -rszpqAclneE ] [ -t [ num ] ] [ -k [ num ] ] [ -d delim ]
#     [ -u n ] [ name[?prompt] ] [ name ... ]
# 
# -q         Read only one character from the terminal and set name to ‘y’ if this character was ‘y’ or ‘Y’
#            and to ‘n’ otherwise. With this flag set the return status is zero only if the character was ‘y’ or ‘Y’.
#            This option may be used with a timeout (see -t); if the read times out, or encounters end of file,
#            status 2 is returned. Input is read from the terminal unless one of -u or -p is present.
#            This option may also be used within zle widgets.
# -r         Raw mode: a ‘\’ at the end of a line does not signify line continuation and backslashes in the line
#            don’t quote the following character and are not removed.

if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
  read -r -q "answer?"
else
  read -r -n 1 answer
fi
echo "$answer"
```

Thanks to [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741542/olaf-dietsche) for his [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174634/14966).