# Programmatically emulating and capturing a shell as a terminal

Tags: node.js, zsh, spawn

I want to use node.js to capture the output of a shell so that I can send it to another process, and also send input to the shell as if I was a user using the terminal (this is for an automation tool).  I have managed to accomplish the latter (sending commands and input to the shell), but I am still missing some of the output from the terminal.

I have posted a specific question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75963963/getting-the-full-output-from-child-process-in-node-js-using-child-process) on this problem, but  I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish the high-level goal.  Maybe a node.js script isn't the correct approach.  Are there better tools or existing APIs for doing what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is to connect the child process to a pseudo terminal (pty) instead of plain pipes. This looks like a normal terminal to the child, but is actually an emulator that allows the parent to interact with it through pipes.

In the shell, this can be done with programs like `expect` or `script`. Most high-level languages have a way to run child processes in a pty, maybe using an external library. It looks like the [`child_pty`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child_pty) package is designed to do this in node.js.