# Install using pip hangs on package license agreement

Tags: python

My company requires that when we distribute a python package we must include a license agreement that the installer must agree to before the install proceeds.  Any way to make pip interactive?

Example:
pip install mypackage

No hanky panky!

Do you agree to the terms? : y

pip install continues....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried piping [`yes`](http://ss64.com/bash/yes.html)?

```bash
yes | pip install mypackage
```

**EDIT:**

I don't think [`pip`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) can do that, but you can script it:

```bash
cat license.txt
read -p "Do you agree to the terms? " -n 1 -r
echo    # (optional) move to a new line
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    pip install mypackage
fi
```

*Brutally stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885534/1178781*

Comment: I think the question is how to make `pip` block and ask for confirmation, not how to provide the confirmation.