# My for loop with Yes/No give diverent output

Tags: batch-file, scripting

Sometimes I press Y it goes to :no

And sometimes I press N it goes to :yes

What am I doing wrong?

Now the loop should go 3 times that's not the problem

Only the call is made is never good.

Hope someone can help me

```
CD %INSTALLDIR%
SET test=
FOR /f %%a in ('dir /b /o:-n') do (
SET test=%%a
  ECHO Generate a answer file for %test%?
  set INPUT=
  set /P INPUT=[Y/N]:
  IF /I '%INPUT%'=='y' call :yes
  IF /I '%INPUT%'=='n' call :no
  )
  goto end
:yes
cd %test%
  SET APPNAME=<%test%.options
  for /f "tokens=1*" %%b in (%test%.options) do set OPTIONS=%%b 
  echo %APPNAME%
  echo %OPTIONS%
goto end

:no
echo Skipping %%a
goto end

:end
ECHO NEXT
```

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885534/3827280

Comment: Try `goto :eof`. See `call /?` and `goto /?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every environment variable referenced with `%VariableName%` within a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` is expanded during preprocessing of entire command block by Windows command interpreter before executing the command which finally executes the already preprocessed command block.

This means `%INPUT%` is replaced by the value of environment variable `INPUT` before command **FOR** is executed at all. The environment variable `INPUT` is not defined in the batch file above command **FOR** and so the comparisons in the command block depend on existence of this environment variable and its current value on starting the batch file.

Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read the help output into the console window. The usage of [delayed environment variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is explained by the help on an **IF** and a **FOR** example on which command blocks are used usually.

But there is a better solution for this task then enabling delayed expansion. Instead of using `set /P INPUT=[Y/N]:` the command **CHOICE** is used which exits with an exit code assigned to `ERRORLEVEL` depending on key pressed by the user. In this case `ERRORLEVEL` is `1` if the user presses `Y` or `y` as being the first specified option or `2` if `N` or `n` is pressed by the user. Other values are not possible.

See also Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576) explaining how `ERRORLEVEL` can be evaluated in a batch file even within a command block without usage of delayed expansion.

```
cd /D "%INSTALLDIR%"
for /F %%I in ('dir /AD /B /O:-N 2^>nul') do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C YN /N /M "Generate an answer file for %%I [Y/N]? "
    if errorlevel 2 (echo Skipping %%I) else call :GetOptions "%%I"
)
goto :EOF

:GetOptions
cd /D "%~1"
set APPNAME=<"%~1.options"
for /F "usebackq" %%J in ("%~1.options") do set "OPTIONS=%%J"
echo %APPNAME%
echo %OPTIONS%
goto :EOF
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cd /?`
- `choice /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `<` and `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

See also [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)