# Whats the best way to add warning when branching off any other branch than master branch in Git

Tags: git

I rarely create branches off of anything but `master` in my daily workflow (maybe an occasionally bug fix on a release branch, etc...).  With rebasing and merge squashing you can end up with a left over branch you really don't want to start a new branch from accidentally or you'll be stuck cleaning up a merge mess when you try to merge the new one into `master` (not realizing you didn't branch initially off of `master`).

I'd like a little warning when I create a new branch if the current working branch isn't `master`, like `"Warning: Hey, you're not branching off master--think about it!"`

What the best way to add this type of simple message?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a pre-checkout hook.
Not the actual code, but, you can do something like:

```
branch=$(git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
if [ $branch != master ]; then
    << do_you_want_to_checkout_anyway? >>
    if [ user_answered_ok ]; then exit 0
    else exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Save it as pre-checkout (no extension) and save it in the your project's `.git/hooks`

For reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Looks promising, but don't have that hook in version of git using currently.

Comment: No, you shouldn't, this is a new, custom one.
This looks interesting for the yes/no  prompt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885534/2502753